# What's the difference between `traceIO` and `hPutStrLn stderr`?

Tags: debugging, haskell

Looking at the description for [`traceIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceIO), I feel that it does exactly what `hPutStrLn stderr` does. However when I looked into its source code:

```
traceIO :: String -> IO ()
traceIO msg = do
    withCString "%s\n" $ \cfmt -> do
     -- NB: debugBelch can't deal with null bytes, so filter them
     -- out so we don't accidentally truncate the message.  See Trac #9395
     let (nulls, msg') = partition (=='\0') msg
     withCString msg' $ \cmsg ->
      debugBelch cfmt cmsg
     when (not (null nulls)) $
       withCString "WARNING: previous trace message had null bytes" $ \cmsg ->
         debugBelch cfmt cmsg
```

It seems it uses a foreign routine called `debugBelch`, which I failed to find any documentation about. So what does `traceIO` do that can't be done by `hPutStrLn stderr`?

Answer (score 5):

One thing I can think of is that it might ensure that the string is printed as a unit, without any other trace messages inside. Indeed an experiment seems to confirm this:

```
Prelude Debug.Trace System.IO> traceIO $ "1" ++ trace "2" "3"
2
13
Prelude Debug.Trace System.IO> hPutStrLn stderr $ "1" ++ trace "2" "3"
12
3
```

Another difference is that it seems to remove characters that cannot safely be printed to stderr:

```
Prelude Debug.Trace System.IO> hPutStrLn stderr "\9731"
*** Exception: <stderr>: hPutChar: invalid argument (invalid character)
Prelude Debug.Trace System.IO> traceIO "\9731"

Prelude Debug.Trace System.IO>
```

As @dfeuer reminds me of, none of these features would be impossible to write in Haskell.  So the deciding factor is probably this: [`debugBelch`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/c5911479f295242e16e396eb5d1369f2e4ce8de0/includes/rts/Messages.h#L78) is already a predefined C function, used [all over the place](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=debugBelch) in GHC's runtime system, which is written in C and C--, not Haskell.

Comment: Couldn't it `evaluate $ force msg` first to avoid interference?

Comment: @dfeuer You're right, this *could* be done directly from Haskell. It's just already available as a C function. I've edited my answer with a note on this.